# A COM exception has been encountered: At Invoke of: AddItem Description: 80004002 / No such interface supported

Tags: java, c#, jacob

I am trying to invoke one function of a C# application from Java application using Jacob COM interface. I got the ActiveXComponent from the registry entry. I have to call one method

```
BaseElement AddItem(
    string name,
    ElementType type
)
```

here ElementType  is an `ENUM` in the `C#` application. But I am not able to get the elsemnt type using invokeGetComponent/getPropertyAsComponent.

Interestingly I am able to call the same method as below,

```
ActiveXComponent appHandler= new ActiveXComponent("Application_name");
ActiveXComponent projectHandler = appHandler.invokeGetComponent("CreateProject", new Variant("C:\\temp"), new Variant("test"));

projectHandler.invokeGetComponent("AddItem", new Variant("item1"),new Variant(0));
```

This method is doing its duty using integer instead of ElementType but throwing exception

> com.jacob.com.ComFailException: A COM exception has been encountered:
>   At Invoke of: AddItem
>   Description: 80004002 / No such interface supported
>         at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Native Method)
>         at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.invokev(Dispatch.java:625)
>         at com.jacob.com.Dispatch.callN(Dispatch.java:453)
>         at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.invoke(ActiveXComponent.java:476)
>         at com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent.invokeGetComponent(ActiveXComponent.java:391)

Is there any ways to get the ENUM type ElementType given in the application ? Seems like the ElementType is in another namespace in C#.

Comment: The ENUM  ElementType have numbers as below,
value1 (0),
value2(1),
value3(2)

and somehow this conversion is happening in C# application. But the exception is always thrown

Comment: able use this function successfully from C# code. 

application = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Application_name"));
                Type elementtype1 = application.GetType().Assembly.GetType("ElementType");
                object obj1= Enum.Parse(elementtype1, "value1");
.........
                object item1 = CallCOMMethod(project1, "AddItem", new object[] { "Item1", obj1});